# Create a custom Validation rule that accepts two input parameters

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a custom Validation rule that accepts one input argument.

```
Validator::extend('dns', function($attribute, $host, $parameters)
{
    return ($host !== gethostbyname($host));
});
```

The rules

```
public static $rules = array(
    'nameserver'    => 'dns'
);
```

I have created a new file called *validators.php* and *include* it in the *global.php* file in  order to be global.

I want to pass two input arguments in order to make some more checks compare to each other.
How can I succeed this?

Answer (score 1):

send extra parameters like:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'nameserver'    => 'dns:foobar'
);
```

and access those via:

```
$parameters[0]
```

in the closure.

[edit]
A way to seed the validator rules with input:

```
// model
static $rules = array(
     'valOne' => 'required|custom:%s'
    ,'valTwo' => 'required'
);

// controller
$inputValues = Input::only(array(
     'valOne'
    ,'valTwo'
));

$rules = MyModel::$rules;

$rules['valOne'] = sprintf($rules['valOne'], Input::get('valTwo'));

$validator = Validator::make($inputValues, $rules);
```

Comment: My rules are inside my model. Your above example passes string `'foobar'` inside my filter. How am I going to pass the value of the `'foobar'` input field?

Comment: Does the 'dns' validation really needs values from other inputs? Perhaps you can validate those in a seperate validation rule. If not, perhaps you can do something with str_replace for the value in  $rules['nameserver'] with input::get('foobar'). (when creating the validator)

Comment: My goal is to validate if `ip` points to the `DNS` that was given. So I need both input field. I assume there is no such a thing *built-in* in `Laravel`. I guess I can say `Input::get()`, but isn't there a better option?

Comment: Not at the moment without a 'dirty' fix (aka feeding input vars in the rules while building the validator). Checkin ip and dns seems like a task wich can take some time, maybe suitable for a background process?

Comment: I think I'd prefer to use session variables rather than `Input::get()`.

Comment: @RobGordijn Why use background process? It's synchronous procedure. We don't want to proceed if validation fails.

Comment: @user1669496 Why use a session? There are input values .